# JavaScript brackets many functions

Tags: javascript

I have 4 functions calling one after another:

```
var res = f1(f2(f3(f4(f5(a, b), 1, 2, true))))
```

Is there any  cleaner way to refactor this.
I want to be able to see the parameters and the code should be minimal.

I can do it like this:

```
let s1 = f5(a, b);
let s2 = f4(s1, 1, 2, true);
let res = f1(f2(f3(s2)))
```

But i dont want to introduce another variables.

can i do it short and easy to read/refactor.

Thanks

Comment: well, this currently does not compile : there is not the same number of  closing brackets as opening ones.

Comment: Related: [ESNext Proposal: The Pipeline Operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) or [JavaScript: Function Composition](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-functional-composition-for-every-day-use-22421ef65a10)

Comment: Well, you can store the functions into an array and then execute reduce.  But I think it's overkill.

Comment: The pipeline operator is currently a proposal, but that's not going to be a viable option in production for a while. I'd say if you're always gonna call them in this order, just define a helper function: `f_all = (a, b, c, d, e) => f1(f2(f3(f4(f5(a, b), c, d, e))));` You can also look into Ramda if you use a lot of composition

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = f1(f2(f3(f4(f5(a, b), 1, 2, true))))
```

> Is there any cleaner way to refactor this. I want to be able to see the parameters and the code should be minimal.

That seems pretty minimal to me.

since f1, f2 and f3  have only their result as parameter, you *could* merge them into one function f123.

But I don't see how this would be really helpful for you as a developer.

5 functions calls is not *that* horrible.

---

> I can do it like this:

```
let s1 = f5(a, b);
let s2 = f4(s1, 1, 2, true);
let res = f1(f2(f3(s2)))
```

> But i dont want to introduce another variables.

I very much like the way with additional intermediate variables. *this* make the code easy to read for another developer (including yourself 2 weeks later from now)

I don't understand why it is a problem for you. Could you elaborate more ?

---

Another possiblity is to use some pipelining machinery. That would *absolutely not be minimal code*, but that could make the code clearer by making the logical order of operations more apparent.

For instance : Observable (RxJS)

```
Observable.of(f5(a,b))
          .map(r5 => f4(r5, 1, 2, true))
          .map(r4 => f3(r4))
          .map(r3 => f2(r3))
          .map(r2 => f1(r2))
          .subscribe(r => console.log(r))
```

But in a sense, you would have some "intermediate variables" represented by the parameter of the lambda expressions.

Comment: I like the observable version, I thougth something with pipe: let r = pipe(_ => f4(a, b), f3, f2, f1)(f5(a,b))

Comment: @user2693928 you are perfectly right ! Pipe would me much better suited in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = f1(
    f2(
        f3(
            f4(
                f5(a, b), 
                1, 
                2, 
                true
            )
        )
    )
);
```

or just save the results in vars...

```
var result_f5 = f5(a, b);
var result_f4 = f4(result_f5, 1, 2, true);
var result_f3 = f3(result_f4);
var result_f2 = f2(result_f3);
var result_f1 = f1(result_f2);
```

I prefer the second way...
There is no other "quicker" or "cleaner" way

Comment: The first example is just reformatting, not refactoring; and OP said they'd prefer not to introduce new variables

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce from the right side, but it needs the nested function `f4` with `f5` as start value.

```
var x = [f1, f2, f3].reduceRight((x, f) => f(x), f4(f5(a, b), 1, 2, true));
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   start value
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                        functions
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the most readable and clean way is to add another function that makes this sequence of function calls. I.e:

```
function f0 (a, b, c, d, e) { return f1(f2(f3(f4(f5(a, b), c, d, e)))); }
```

then simply call:

```
var res = f0(a, b, 1, 2, true);
```

Comment: It  is good but how will i call the function, these 5,6 functions are specific and i cannot think of a good function name. it will be something like: getAgeAndFormatUsernameAndAppendCompanyThenFilterActive :)

Comment: @user2693928 if you're making changes to the same data set, then you might consider chaining.. like this `var res = data.getAge(18).formatUserName("%g").AppendCompany().filterActive(true);`.. it's readable, customizable and common (e.g. fluent interface pattern).

Answer (score 0):

```
// consider this function as small library or hidden part.
// it's composition/high-order function
var f = (func, ...rest) => {
    if(typeof func === "function") {
        if(this.__res)
            this.__res = func(this.__res, ...rest)
        else
            this.__res = func(...rest)
        return f
    } else {
        var result = this.__res
        this.__res = undefined
        return result
    }
}

// the real part you want is here
var res = f(f5, a, b)(f4, 1,2,true)(f3)(f2)(f1)()
```

I know you don't want to introduce another variables.
but when you consider function f as hidden part of a library or module/package, f(f5, a, b)(f4, 1,2,true)(f3)(f2)(f1)() is more readable and clean, isn't it?

Comment: very nice indeed :). I wanted to get rid of "this" but in  the case it is worth using it